# Compress HTML and extract with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I know you are going to shudder but here's what I would like to be able to do:

I would like the html to look like this when it's downloaded:

```
<t><r>
  <d c="b" s="w: 1px;"></d>
  <d c="i" s="w: 99px;"></d>
  <d c="t" s="w: 1px;"></d>
  <d c="u" s="w: 6px;"></d>
<r></t>
```

And then modify it with javascript to the real deal after download:

```
<table><tr>
  <td class="b" style="width: 1px;"></td>
  <td class="i" style="width: 99px;"></td>
  <td class="t" style="width: 1px;"></td>
  <td class="u" style="width: 6px;"></td>
<tr></table>
```

Is this even possible?

EDIT: The answer with code since I can't answer my own questions until 8 hours?!?!

Ok, works fine!

Here is the code for [rupy](http://rupy.googlecode.com):

```
public static class Stats extends Service {
    public String path() { return "/stats.html"; }
    public void filter(Event event) throws Event, Exception {
        event.reply().header("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

        File file = new File("app/content/stats.html.gzip");
        file.createNewFile();

        GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("app/content/stats.html");

        Deploy.pipe(in, out);

        in.close();

        out.finish();
        out.close();

        in = new FileInputStream(file);

        Deploy.pipe(in, event.reply().output(file.length()));

        in.close();
    }
}
```

My file is not something that needs performace, in that case you would ofcourse gzip it on writes and not reads...

Comment: You can do this using some string replacement, maybe regexp, but I doubt it is worth the effort.

Comment: _"Is this even possible?"_ - Yep. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: If your using gzip compression on your pages this is really unnecessary.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, but it will be worth it because I have alot of these tables... I know the best would be to gzip on the http level, but I'm wondering how this will perform with dynamic pages (I guess gzip needs buffering)... this just became a java webserver question: I need to add gzip to [rupy](http://rupy.googlecode.com)!

Comment: hmm wait couldn't I just gzip the whole file and send it with a gzip header... yes, ok solved! doesent work for dynamic pages but for this it's perfect, thx all!